# how to avoid onCreateView be called in side Fragments on tab swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity and 4 swipeable tabs(fragments). For example I have a Custom Toast and a PostResponseAsyncTask to execute in my Fragment #3 that shows a loading progress, but this Toast and loading progress view also comes up in my Fragment #4 and #2 while swiping.. what is the correct way for me to handle this ..

I would be so grateful if you guide me through based on this example

**this is Fragment #3(contains Toast and execute)**

```
public class A extends Fragment {
View view ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx_updates_layout, container, false);


     PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(getActivity(), this);
     taskRead.execute("http://symphonyrecords.6te.net/product.php");

    //Custom Toast
    LayoutInflater inflaterToast = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflaterToast.inflate(R.layout.d_toast_d,
             (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_people);
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Ringtone Bank");
    Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();


    return view;
  } //onCreate
}
```

**This is fragment #4(don't want the Toast and execute comes up here)**

```
public class XXXFOUR extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx_four,null);
  }
 }
```

**And this is my viewpager and FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class XXXTabFragment extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 4 ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx_tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));



    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
               }
    });

    return x;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
      switch (position){
          case 0 : return new XXXPrimaryFragment();
          case 1 : return new XXXSocialFragment();
          case 2 : return new XXXUpdatesFragment();
          case 3 : return new XXXFOUR();
      }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Primary";
            case 1 :
                return "Social";
            case 2 :
                return "Updates";
            case 3 :
                return "Four";
        }
            return null;
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Must you need the custom view to toast? or Simple text is enough?

Comment: It's better to have customized one but it's not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swiping tabs, this is a common problem and reason for having this is smooth performance experience while swiping.

I would suggest to override below method and manage if fragment is visible by one variable.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible=true;
}
```

otherwise move all the above in one function and execute it from `setUserVisibleHint`.

Comment: As i am new in android if you could explain it a little more i would be more thankfull

Comment: please find detail answer on this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/893f3495dd4d2695b16d22473ff6f80c

Comment: I could't understand how to create this (pages) variable and list my fragments in it , but i used setUserVisibleHint and put my tasks inside it and solved this problem for now , so thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In each fragment use this

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            //Do what to perform such as toast or PostResponseAsyncTask accordingly here.
        }
    }
```

also you could set a listner so that each time a corespponding tab is selected it will trigger the function as you want

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                selectedTabPosition = tab.getPosition();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedTabPosition);
                setList(selectedTabPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can toast text only, you can use [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Ringtone Bank", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[Displaying the Snackbar](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-the-Snackbar)

*Toast* sometimes will not disappear when your activity itself paused(when  you pressed home button) also, but since you are adding the *Snackbar* with the `parentView` it will display only on your current screen.

Comment: That is a good advice and i will surly consider this(thank you) , but the toast is one of my problems , i need a primary solution that covers the whole stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class A extends Fragment {

Toast toast;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(!isVisibleToUser){
        toast.cancel();
    }
}
```